# EditText position for the input promt

Tags: android, android-studio

Is it possible to specify where the input promt shows on the screen when using the EditText field in android studio?
i have a layer on the bottom of the screen, and it makes the last row disappear.
I want to have the input promt showing just above my layer, if it is possible.

[image]

Comment: Post the layout(s) if you can.

Comment: `code

            <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:inputType="numberPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
`

Comment: You can use PopDialog for that.

Comment: I need to retrive the numeric user input, dosent seems like you could do that with a pop dialog?